# creating multiple instances of an object in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, oop

Hey I'm working on a game that involves spawning a number of different enemies on a game board. I've created an enemy object with randoms speeds and locations, and I've pushed that object to an array.

How can I now multiply the number of enemies in my array?

```
const allEnemies = []; 

let bugSpeed = randomNumber(5, 25) * 10;
let bugRow = randomNumber(1, 4);
enemy = new Enemy(bugRow, bugSpeed);

allEnemies.push(enemy);
```

Comment: Put all four bottom lines in a loop and iterate the number of times you want enemies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `multiply` method on you class that takes a number and return clones of current instance using `Array.from` method.

```js
const allEnemies = [];
class Enemy {
  constructor(row, speed) {
    this.row = row;
    this.speed = speed;
  }

  multiply(number) {
    return Array.from(Array(number), () => {
      return Object.assign(new Enemy, this);
    })
  }
}

const enemy = new Enemy(1, 3);

allEnemies.push(...enemy.multiply(5));
allEnemies[1].speed = 123;
console.log(allEnemies[1].multiply(3));
console.log(allEnemies)
```

Comment: Also consider using static method for this.

Answer (score 2):

Posting out the pure javascript version of the same ;

```
Enemy.prototype.multiply = function(multiplyBy){
   var that = this;
   Array.from(Array(multiplyBy), function(){
      var newEnemy = Object.assign(new enemy, that);
      allEnemies.push(newEnemy);
   });
}
```

Comment: How would I implement this if I wanted to multiplyBy 5?

Comment: Simply call the multiply function with Enemy object reference. var enemy = new Enemy(your params); enemy.multiply(5);